# How to change the image within a button when it has an active class to demonstrate open and close functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple menu component with a button that when clicked shows a navigation menu (classic hamburger menu).

Whenever the kitten img is clicked, an `active` class is applied and the nav-menu is made visible. However, I need to replace the kitten img with a different img when it is open so that the user can clearly see the menu can be closed.

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu-toggle');
const navMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-menu');

// Toggle hamburger menu
hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hamburger.classList.toggle('active');
  navMenu.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 56px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.hamburger-icon {
  display: flex;
  width: 16.67%;
}

.mobile-menu-toggle {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.heading {
  display: flex;
  width: 58%;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: -100%;
  top: 56px;
  gap: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-menu.active {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav">
  <div class="hamburger-icon">
    <button class="mobile-menu-toggle">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/1440/671" height=24 width=24 />
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="heading">My menu
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Sign up</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use 2 buttons with same functionality but different images. And then you can show one button while hide the other in same place. So basically one button replaces the other button in case if the menu is showing or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click the image check if class active then change image other wise set the prev image

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu-toggle');
const navMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-menu');

// Toggle hamburger menu
hamburger.addEventListener('click', (e) => {     
     
    hamburger.classList.toggle('active');
    if(hamburger.classList.contains('active')){
        e.target.src = 'https://placekitten.com/1440/672'
     }
     else{
         e.target.src = 'https://placekitten.com/1440/671'
     }
  navMenu.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 56px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.hamburger-icon {
  display: flex;
  width: 16.67%;
}

.mobile-menu-toggle {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.heading {
  display: flex;
  width: 58%;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: -100%;
  top: 56px;
  gap: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-menu.active {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav">
  <div class="hamburger-icon">
    <button class="mobile-menu-toggle">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/1440/671" height=24 width=24 />
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="heading">My menu
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Sign up</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - this seems like a really straightforward solution, one thing though - any thoughts on how to handle updated alt text to reflect changed icon?

Answer (score 1):

You can add two images inside the button, `.active` and `.inactive` and use css to show and hide based on parent is active or not.

something like this :

```
<button class="mobile-menu-toggle">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/1440/671" height=24 width=24 class="inactive" />
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/1440/670" height=24 width=24 class="active" />
 </button>
```

css:

```
.mobile-menu-toggle img.active,
.mobile-menu-toggle.active img.inactive {
  display: none;
}

.mobile-menu-toggle.active img.active,
.mobile-menu-toggle img.inactive {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/kouj7xzf/10/).

Comment: This is best solution, Love this !

Answer (score 1):

I have removed the img tags from HTML, and stored them in variables in JS.
Cleared the innerHTML in hamburger and inserted an image which you want to see by default and changing kitty images dynamically.

```js
'use strict'
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu-toggle');
const navMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-menu');


const opened_img_html = `<img class="opened_img" src="https://placekitten.com/1440/671" height=24 width=24 />`;
const closed_img_html = `<img class="closed_img" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" height=24 width=24 />`;



hamburger.innerHTML = '';
hamburger.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', opened_img_html);

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {

  if (hamburger.lastChild.matches('.opened_img')) {
    hamburger.innerHTML = '';
    hamburger.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', closed_img_html);
    toggle_classes()
  }
  else {
    hamburger.innerHTML = '';
    hamburger.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', opened_img_html);
    toggle_classes()
  }

});

function toggle_classes() {
  hamburger.classList.toggle('active');
  navMenu.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: grey;
    min-height: 56px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
}

.hamburger-icon {
    display: flex;
    width: 16.67%;
}

.mobile-menu-toggle {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.heading {
    display: flex;
    width: 58%;
}

.nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: -100%;
    top: 56px;
    gap: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-menu.active {
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main-nav">
        <div class="hamburger-icon">
            <button class="mobile-menu-toggle">
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="heading">My menu
            <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Sign up</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```